# active client - get token from resource partner adfs using idp token

Tags: c#, wcf, saml, claims-based-identity, adfs2.0

I am trying to write console application with the following scenario:
client first requests a token from an identity provider, and then uses this token to request a new token from a Resource STS
Using the following link: http://leastprivilege.com/2010/10/28/wif-adfs-2-and-wcfpart-6-chaining-multiple-token-services/

I managed get the token from Idp but didn't managed getting the token from Resource STS.

This is my code:

```
    string RPRealm = "https://service.contoso.com/";
    string RSTSRealm = "http://fsweb.contoso.com/adfs/services/trust";
    string IdPstsEndpoint = "https://IdpAdfs.domain.com/adfs/services/trust/13/kerberosmixed";
    string RSTSEndpoint = "https://fsweb.contoso.com/adfs/services/trust/13/IssuedTokenMixedSymmetricBasic256";

    private static SecurityToken GetIdPToken(string rstsRealm, string IdPstsEndpoint)
    {
        using (var factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(
                new KerberosWSTrustBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential),
                new EndpointAddress(new Uri(IdPstsEndpoint))))
        {
            WSTrustChannel channel = null;
            factory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;
            try
            {
                var rst = new RequestSecurityToken
                {
                    RequestType = WSTrust13Constants.RequestTypes.Issue,
                    AppliesTo = new EndpointAddress(rstsRealm),
                    KeyType = WSTrust13Constants.KeyTypes.Bearer,
                };

                channel = (WSTrustChannel)factory.CreateChannel();
                RequestSecurityTokenResponse rstr;
                SecurityToken token = channel.Issue(rst, out rstr);
                return token;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (channel != null)
                {
                    channel.Abort();
                }

                factory.Abort();
            }
        }
    }


private static SecurityToken GetRSTSToken(SecurityToken IdPToken, string RSTSEndpoint, string RPRealm)
{
   var binding = new WS2007FederationHttpBinding();
   binding.Security.Message.IssuedKeyType = SecurityKeyType.BearerKey;
   binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
   binding.Security.Mode = WSFederationHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;

    using (var factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(
           binding,
            new EndpointAddress(new Uri(RSTSEndpoint))))
    {
        var rst = new RequestSecurityToken
        {
            RequestType = WSTrust13Constants.RequestTypes.Issue,
            AppliesTo = new EndpointAddress(RPRealm),
            KeyType = WSTrust13Constants.KeyTypes.Bearer,
        };
        factory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
        factory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;
        factory.Credentials.SupportInteractive = false;
        factory.ConfigureChannelFactory();


        var channel = factory.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken(IdPToken);
        RequestSecurityTokenResponse rstr;
        SecurityToken token = channel.Issue(rst, out rstr);
        return token;
    }
}
```

I get this error:
The content type text/html of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8)
what is worng with my code?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using the WSTrust-Bindings in Thinktecture.IdentityModel - e.g. for the 2nd hop use the IssuedTokenWSTrustBinding.

Comment: If i use IssuedTokenWSTrustBinding,i get error: 
The signing token Generic XML token:
   validFrom: 05/05/2013 14:51:22
   validTo: 05/05/2013 15:51:22
   InternalTokenReference: SamlAssertionKeyIdentifierClause(AssertionId = '_29979767-107a-4c16-b59b-4a9462edfea3')
   ExternalTokenReference:SamlAssertionKeyIdentifierClause(AssertionId = '_29979767-107a-4c16-b59b-4a9462edfea3')
   Token Element: (EncryptedData, http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#)
 has no keys. The security token is used in a context that requires it to perform cryptographic operations, but the token contains no cryptographic...

Answer (score 2):

ADFS does not support bearer tokens on its federation endoints. In other words, on your first hop you need to specify a KeyTypes.Symmetric on the RST.